# Monitoring the progress of a calculation over a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have a function which I run over a list of values. Is there some way to monitor the progress of this? Perhaps have it take values in a list but as it computes for each element of the list, print the result? Of course, I could run each value individually of course, but since I generate the parameter values as a list it would be more effort to run each parameter value individually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `Print[]`, `PrintTemporary[]` or `Echo[]` to your function definition.

```
ClearAll[fun] ;
fun[x_] := (Pause[1]; Echo[x] ; x)
list = Range[10] ;
Map[fun,list]

ClearAll[fun] ;
fun[x_] := (Pause[1]; PrintTemporary[x] ; x)
list = Range[10] ;
Map[fun,list]
```

Also `Dynamic[]` and `Monitor[]` can be used:

```
ClearAll[fun] ;
fun[x_] := (Pause[1]; Dynamic[count] ; count++ ; x)
count = 1 ;
list = Range[10] ;
Monitor[Map[fun,list],ProgressIndicator[count,{1, Length[list]}]]
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's a solution using [`ResourceFunction["MonitorProgress"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MonitorProgress):

```
fun[x_] := (Pause@1(*some long computation *);x^2)

ResourceFunction["MonitorProgress"][fun /@ Range@5]
(* {1, 4, 9, 16, 25} *)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! Does using this for long lists (e.g. 50000 elements) cause a significant slow-down?

Comment: @Sterling I tried my best to keep the overhead as low as possible, but I would suggest to simply test how big the performance impact is for you, since it will vary from case to case.